# Pinning Combination

Tags: tactics, problems, pins

There are are four types of [pins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pin_(chess)).

1. Absolute Pin-A piece is pinned to the king and cannot move due to the resulting illegal check.
2. Partial Pin-A piece is pinned to the king and can move along pinning line but nowhere to else due to the resulting illegal check.
3. Relative Pin-A piece is not pinned to king and can move but doing so would lose the exchange.
4. Situational Pin-A pinned piece can move butdoing so is dettered by a loss of material or mate.

I am looking for a combination played in a real game that demonstrates all four kinds of pins, preferably in a row in any combination of the four pins.

The best I can find is a [mate in two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrX8J.png) combination with two absolute pins in a row.

```
[FEN "rnbq1r2/pp2kpQp/3p4/1B6/3Np3/B1b5/P1P2PPP/1R1K3R w - - 0 1"]

1. Qe5+ Be6 2. Nf5#
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a game that shows all four in a combination. However, here is a chess problem that I made to demonstrate all 4 types of pins in a "combination-esque" sequence.

```
[Title "me, chess.stackexchange.com 8/19/2020, Mate In 4"]
[FEN "1K6/NP3p2/8/p5Pb/kr1RRPPp/3P2Nq/1Pp3PQ/2nB2B1 w - - 0 1"]

1. Bxc2+ Nb3 {An absolute pin is instated to limit Black's move choices and to lock up the Black king} 2. Qxh3 hxg3 {After White moves, Black's pawn is in a relative pin. This is because moving it exposes the higher-valued bishop to capture. If Black's bishop moves, White can still mates in two} (2... Bxg4 3. Ne2 null 4. Nc3#) 3. Qxh5 {Now Black's two moveable pieces are pinned. The pawn is in a situational pin because moving it results in a mate, and the rook is in a partial pin because it can only move along the pin line, although it is also in a situational pin.} f5 (3... Rc4 4. Rxc4#) 4. Qe8#
```

Addendum 12/17/2020-Here is a shorter, less complicated version of the above problem, being one move shorter, fewer units used, and much cleaner play.

```
[Title "me, chess.stackexchange.com 12/17/2020, Mate In 3"]
[FEN "8/N4p2/8/p1P2PPr/kr1R2pp/1r1P2NQ/1PR1P1P1/3BK3 w - - 0 1"]

1. Rcc4! {This instates an absolute pin on Black's b3 rook, and a partial pin on their b4 rook.} hxg3 (1... gxh3 2. Ne4 null 3. Nc3#) {Black's h4 pawn was in a relative pin. If it doesn't move, White mates with the knight, and if it does, Black loses the higher valued rook. } 2. Qxh5 {Now Black's pawn is in a situational pin, as moving it will result in mate. Black's rook is also in the same predicament.} f6 (2... Rxc4 3. Rxc4#) 3. Qe8#
```